# The Witcher 2 - The Butcher of Cidaris Quest Bug?

Tags: pc, the-witcher-2

This is my first playthrough and I think I started this quest without realising it.

When I first got to Chapter 2 there was too much going on at once and so it got slightly confusing, so a lot of Quests were added and some where overlooked to begin with, this Quest been one of them.

Anyway, after progressing through the story I have to enter the fog to kill some of the spirits (after going to the hideout place), but if I enter the fog I fail The Butcher of Cidaris Quest (Also failed the Little Sisters quest, but I managed to complete this)

Before continuing with the story I want to complete as much as I can, the objective for this Quest now is to go and speak to the veteran soldier in the camp canteen. The problem is the soldier is not there, there is only the relic peddler and someone asking for orens for some book or something.

So is this a bug or am I missing something? I believe this quest lets you fight in the arena which I want to do. I think his name was Manfred if I am not mistaken, but I cannot find him anywhere and I have looked all through the camp.

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect that by advancing in the main quest you missed the chance to speak to the father in the canteen. It might be a bug or an oversight, but if the father is not in the canteen you probably can't continue the quest.

Comment: this is the only thing I dont like with some games like this that it is possible you can miss and fail some things. I probably missed it, I just wanted to explore chapter 2 and in doing so ended up forgetting about this Quest. I like to take my time in these kind of games and am also a bit of a perfectionist, I dont like the way you fail some Quests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the father is no longer in the canteen then you have probably progressed too far in this Chapter to be able to complete this quest. He should be in the canteen, at the right most table. If he isn't there, then you definitely have a problem as he does not wander around camp or frequent any other tents.

I'm not sure how much farther you've gotten but my only suggestion at this point would be to load a previous save. I would especially do so if you are trying for a romance scene with Ves because the arena fight is the only way to make that happen.

Comment: dammit I probably went too far, and I dont have any saves that go that far back.

Comment: @craig - are you sure? Have you turned off the auto-save options? The Witcher 2 is pretty good about never deleting autosaves.

Comment: @Raven, I deleted them when there were too many saves it slowed down the game menus for some reason. apart from the most current saves i did not delete. Dam this will be the 3rd restart and I have not even got past chapter 2.